# why is ray Tune with pytorch HPO error 'trials did not complete, incomplete trials'?

Tags: python, pytorch, ray, ray-tune

Could someone explain why this code (that I took from [here](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/getting-started.html)):

```
## Standard libraries
import os
import json
import math
import numpy as np 
import time

## Imports for plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline 
#from IPython.display import set_matplotlib_formats
#set_matplotlib_formats('svg', 'pdf') # For export
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgb
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2.0
import seaborn as sns
sns.reset_orig()
sns.set()
import torch_geometric
import torch_geometric.nn as geom_nn
import torch_geometric.data as geom_data
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import LearningRateMonitor, ModelCheckpoint
## Progress bar
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

## PyTorch
import torch
import torchmetrics
from torchmetrics.functional import precision_recall
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.utils.data as data
import torch.optim as optim
# Torchvision
import torchvision
from torchvision.datasets import CIFAR10
from torchvision import transforms
# PyTorch Lightning
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from ray import tune

def __init__(self, config):
  super(LightningMNISTClassifier, self).__init__()
  self.layer_1_size = config["layer_1_size"]
  self.layer_2_size = config["layer_2_size"]
  self.lr = config["lr"]
  self.batch_size = config["batch_size"]

from ray.tune.integration.pytorch_lightning import TuneReportCallback
callback = TuneReportCallback(
    {
        "loss": "val_loss",
        "mean_accuracy": "val_accuracy"
    },
    on="validation_end")


def train_tune(config, epochs=10, gpus=0):
  model = LightningMNISTClassifier(config)
  trainer = pl.Trainer(
    max_epochs=epochs,
    gpus=gpus,
    progress_bar_refresh_rate=0,
    callbacks=[callback])
  trainer.fit(model)

config = {
  "layer_1_size": tune.choice([32, 64, 128]),
  "layer_2_size": tune.choice([64, 128, 256]),
  "lr": tune.loguniform(1e-4, 1e-1),
  "batch_size": tune.choice([32, 64, 128])
}


def train_tune(config, epochs=10, gpus=0):
  model = LightningMNISTClassifier(config)
  trainer = pl.Trainer(
    max_epochs=epochs,
    gpus=gpus,
    progress_bar_refresh_rate=0,
    callbacks=[callback])
  trainer.fit(model)


from functools import partial
tune.run(
  partial(train_tune, epochs=10, gpus=0),
  config=config,
  num_samples=10)
```

generates this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example_hpo_working.py", line 89, in <module>
    num_samples=10)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/tune.py", line 741, in run
    raise TuneError("Trials did not complete", incomplete_trials)
ray.tune.error.TuneError: ('Trials did not complete', [train_tune_6f362_00000, train_tune_6f362_00001, train_tune_6f362_00002, train_tune_6f362_00003, train_tune_6f362_00004, train_tune_6f362_00005, train_tune_6f362_00006, train_tune_6f362_00007, train_tune_6f362_00008, train_tune_6f362_00009])
```

I can see a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196236/tuneerror-trials-did-not-complete) but not answered (the ultimate aim is to use ray hyperparameter optimisation with a pytorch network).

This is the full trace from the code:

```
2022-08-16 15:44:08,204 WARNING function_runner.py:604 -- Function checkpointing is disabled. This may result in unexpected behavior when using checkpointing features or certain schedulers. To enable, set the train function arguments to be `func(config, checkpoint_dir=None)`.
2022-08-16 15:44:08,411 ERROR syncer.py:147 -- Log sync requires rsync to be installed.
== Status ==
Memory usage on this node: 16.8/86.4 GiB
Using FIFO scheduling algorithm.
Resources requested: 1.0/64 CPUs, 0/0 GPUs, 0.0/62.79 GiB heap, 0.0/9.31 GiB objects
Result logdir: /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08
Number of trials: 10/10 (9 PENDING, 1 RUNNING)
+------------------------+----------+------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
| Trial name             | status   | loc              |   batch_size |   layer_1_size |   layer_2_size |          lr |
|------------------------+----------+------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------|
| train_tune_43fd5_00000 | RUNNING  | 172.17.0.2:41684 |           64 |             64 |            256 | 0.00233834  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00001 | PENDING  |                  |           64 |             64 |            256 | 0.00155955  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00002 | PENDING  |                  |          128 |            128 |             64 | 0.00399358  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00003 | PENDING  |                  |          128 |            128 |             64 | 0.000184477 |

...deleted a few similar lines here

..and then there's:
    

(func pid=41684) 2022-08-16 15:44:10,774        ERROR function_runner.py:286 -- Runner Thread raised error.
(func pid=41684) Traceback (most recent call last):
(func pid=41684)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 277, in run
(func pid=41684)     self._entrypoint()
(func pid=41684)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 352, in entrypoint
(func pid=41684)     self._status_reporter.get_checkpoint(),
(func pid=41684)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/tracing/tracing_helper.py", line 462, in _resume_span
(func pid=41684)     return method(self, *_args, **_kwargs)
(func pid=41684)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 645, in _trainable_func
(func pid=41684)     output = fn()
(func pid=41684)   File "example_hpo_working.py", line 76, in train_tune
(func pid=41684)     model = LightningMNISTClassifier(config)
(func pid=41684) NameError: name 'LightningMNISTClassifier' is not defined
2022-08-16 15:44:10,977 ERROR trial_runner.py:886 -- Trial train_tune_43fd5_00000: Error processing event.
NoneType: None
Result for train_tune_43fd5_00000:
  date: 2022-08-16_15-44-10
  experiment_id: c8977e85cbf84a9badff15fb2de6f516
  hostname: 0e26c6a24ffa
  node_ip: 172.17.0.2
  pid: 41684
  timestamp: 1660664650
  trial_id: 43fd5_00000
  
(func pid=41722) 2022-08-16 15:44:13,241        ERROR function_runner.py:286 -- Runner Thread raised error.
(func pid=41722) Traceback (most recent call last):
(func pid=41722)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 277, in run
(func pid=41722)     self._entrypoint()
(func pid=41722)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 352, in entrypoint
(func pid=41722)     self._status_reporter.get_checkpoint(),
(func pid=41722)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/tracing/tracing_helper.py", line 462, in _resume_span
(func pid=41722)     return method(self, *_args, **_kwargs)
(func pid=41722)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 645, in _trainable_func
(func pid=41722)     output = fn()
(func pid=41722)   File "example_hpo_working.py", line 76, in train_tune
(func pid=41722)     model = LightningMNISTClassifier(config)
(func pid=41722) NameError: name 'LightningMNISTClassifier' is not defined
(func pid=41720) 2022-08-16 15:44:13,253        ERROR function_runner.py:286 -- Runner Thread raised error.
(func pid=41720) Traceback (most recent call last):
(func pid=41720)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 277, in run
(func pid=41720)     self._entrypoint()
(func pid=41720)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 352, in entrypoint
(func pid=41720)     self._status_reporter.get_checkpoint(),
(func pid=41720)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/tracing/tracing_helper.py", line 462, in _resume_span
(func pid=41720)     return method(self, *_args, **_kwargs)
(func pid=41720)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 645, in _trainable_func
(func pid=41720)     output = fn()
(func pid=41720)   File "example_hpo_working.py", line 76, in train_tune
(func pid=41720)     model = LightningMNISTClassifier(config)
(func pid=41720) NameError: name 'LightningMNISTClassifier' is not defined
(func pid=41718) 2022-08-16 15:44:13,253        ERROR function_runner.py:286 -- Runner Thread raised error.
(func pid=41718) Traceback (most recent call last):
(func pid=41718)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 277, in run
(func pid=41718)     self._entrypoint()
(func pid=41718)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 352, in entrypoint
(func pid=41718)     self._status_reporter.get_checkpoint(),
(func pid=41718)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/tracing/tracing_helper.py", line 462, in _resume_span
(func pid=41718)     return method(self, *_args, **_kwargs)
(func pid=41718)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 645, in _trainable_func
(func pid=41718)     output = fn()
(func pid=41718)   File "example_hpo_working.py", line 76, in train_tune
(func pid=41718)     model = LightningMNISTClassifier(config)
(func pid=41718) NameError: name 'LightningMNISTClassifier' is not defined
(func pid=41734) 2022-08-16 15:44:13,340        ERROR function_runner.py:286 -- Runner Thread raised error.
(func pid=41734) Traceback (most recent call last):
(func pid=41734)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 277, in run
(func pid=41734)     self._entrypoint()
(func pid=41734)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 352, in entrypoint
(func pid=41734)     self._status_reporter.get_checkpoint(),
(func pid=41734)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/tracing/tracing_helper.py", line 462, in _resume_span
(func pid=41734)     return method(self, *_args, **_kwargs)
(func pid=41734)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 645, in _trainable_func
(func pid=41734)     output = fn()
(func pid=41734)   File "example_hpo_working.py", line 76, in train_tune
(func pid=41734)     model = LightningMNISTClassifier(config)
(func pid=41734) NameError: name 'LightningMNISTClassifier' is not defined
(func pid=41732) 2022-08-16 15:44:13,325        ERROR function_runner.py:286 -- Runner Thread raised error.
(func pid=41732) Traceback (most recent call last):
(func pid=41732)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 277, in run
(func pid=41732)     self._entrypoint()
(func pid=41732)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 352, in entrypoint
(func pid=41732)     self._status_reporter.get_checkpoint(),
(func pid=41732)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/tracing/tracing_helper.py", line 462, in _resume_span
(func pid=41732)     return method(self, *_args, **_kwargs)
(func pid=41732)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 645, in _trainable_func
(func pid=41732)     output = fn()
(func pid=41732)   File "example_hpo_working.py", line 76, in train_tune
(func pid=41732)     model = LightningMNISTClassifier(config)
(func pid=41732) NameError: name 'LightningMNISTClassifier' is not defined
(func pid=41728) 2022-08-16 15:44:13,309        ERROR function_runner.py:286 -- Runner Thread raised error.
(func pid=41728) Traceback (most recent call last):
(func pid=41728)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 277, in run
(func pid=41728)     self._entrypoint()
(func pid=41728)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 352, in entrypoint
(func pid=41728)     self._status_reporter.get_checkpoint(),
(func pid=41728)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/tracing/tracing_helper.py", line 462, in _resume_span
(func pid=41728)     return method(self, *_args, **_kwargs)
(func pid=41728)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 645, in _trainable_func
(func pid=41728)     output = fn()
(func pid=41728)   File "example_hpo_working.py", line 76, in train_tune
(func pid=41728)     model = LightningMNISTClassifier(config)
(func pid=41728) NameError: name 'LightningMNISTClassifier' is not defined
(func pid=41730) 2022-08-16 15:44:13,272        ERROR function_runner.py:286 -- Runner Thread raised error.
(func pid=41730) Traceback (most recent call last):
(func pid=41730)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 277, in run
(func pid=41730)     self._entrypoint()
(func pid=41730)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 352, in entrypoint
(func pid=41730)     self._status_reporter.get_checkpoint(),
(func pid=41730)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/tracing/tracing_helper.py", line 462, in _resume_span
(func pid=41730)     return method(self, *_args, **_kwargs)
(func pid=41730)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 645, in _trainable_func
(func pid=41730)     output = fn()
(func pid=41730)   File "example_hpo_working.py", line 76, in train_tune
(func pid=41730)     model = LightningMNISTClassifier(config)
(func pid=41730) NameError: name 'LightningMNISTClassifier' is not defined
2022-08-16 15:44:13,444 ERROR trial_runner.py:886 -- Trial train_tune_43fd5_00003: Error processing event.
NoneType: None
Result for train_tune_43fd5_00003:
  date: 2022-08-16_15-44-13
  experiment_id: 02204d81b72943e3bbfcc822d35f02a0
  hostname: 0e26c6a24ffa
  node_ip: 172.17.0.2
  pid: 41722
  timestamp: 1660664653
  trial_id: 43fd5_00003
  
(func pid=41724) 2022-08-16 15:44:13,457        ERROR function_runner.py:286 -- Runner Thread raised error.
(func pid=41724) Traceback (most recent call last):
(func pid=41724)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 277, in run
(func pid=41724)     self._entrypoint()
(func pid=41724)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 352, in entrypoint
(func pid=41724)     self._status_reporter.get_checkpoint(),
(func pid=41724)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/tracing/tracing_helper.py", line 462, in _resume_span
(func pid=41724)     return method(self, *_args, **_kwargs)
(func pid=41724)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 645, in _trainable_func
(func pid=41724)     output = fn()
(func pid=41724)   File "example_hpo_working.py", line 76, in train_tune
(func pid=41724)     model = LightningMNISTClassifier(config)
(func pid=41724) NameError: name 'LightningMNISTClassifier' is not defined
== Status ==
Current time: 2022-08-16 15:44:13 (running for 00:00:05.24)
Memory usage on this node: 17.6/86.4 GiB
Using FIFO scheduling algorithm.
Resources requested: 8.0/64 CPUs, 0/0 GPUs, 0.0/62.79 GiB heap, 0.0/9.31 GiB objects
Result logdir: /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08
Number of trials: 10/10 (2 ERROR, 8 RUNNING)
+------------------------+----------+------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
| Trial name             | status   | loc              |   batch_size |   layer_1_size |   layer_2_size |          lr |
|------------------------+----------+------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------|
| train_tune_43fd5_00001 | RUNNING  | 172.17.0.2:41718 |           64 |             64 |            256 | 0.00155955  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00002 | RUNNING  | 172.17.0.2:41720 |          128 |            128 |             64 | 0.00399358  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00004 | RUNNING  | 172.17.0.2:41724 |          128 |             64 |            128 | 0.0221855   |
| train_tune_43fd5_00005 | RUNNING  | 172.17.0.2:41726 |           64 |            128 |            128 | 0.00041038  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00006 | RUNNING  | 172.17.0.2:41728 |           64 |             64 |            256 | 0.0105243   |
| train_tune_43fd5_00007 | RUNNING  | 172.17.0.2:41730 |          128 |             32 |            256 | 0.000929454 |
| train_tune_43fd5_00008 | RUNNING  | 172.17.0.2:41732 |           64 |             64 |            128 | 0.00176483  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00009 | RUNNING  | 172.17.0.2:41734 |          128 |             32 |            256 | 0.000113077 |
| train_tune_43fd5_00000 | ERROR    | 172.17.0.2:41684 |           64 |             64 |            256 | 0.00233834  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00003 | ERROR    | 172.17.0.2:41722 |          128 |            128 |             64 | 0.000184477 |
+------------------------+----------+------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
Number of errored trials: 2
+------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Trial name             |   # failures | error file                                                                                                                                                        |
|------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| train_tune_43fd5_00000 |            1 | /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08/train_tune_43fd5_00000_0_batch_size=64,layer_1_size=64,layer_2_size=256,lr=0.0023_2022-08-16_15-44-08/error.txt  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00003 |            1 | /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08/train_tune_43fd5_00003_3_batch_size=128,layer_1_size=128,layer_2_size=64,lr=0.0002_2022-08-16_15-44-10/error.txt |
+------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

2022-08-16 15:44:13,487 ERROR trial_runner.py:886 -- Trial train_tune_43fd5_00001: Error processing event.
NoneType: None
Result for train_tune_43fd5_00001:
  date: 2022-08-16_15-44-13
  experiment_id: e738348e77c64919931d70c916cbfaf8
  hostname: 0e26c6a24ffa
  node_ip: 172.17.0.2
  pid: 41718
  timestamp: 1660664653
  trial_id: 43fd5_00001
  
2022-08-16 15:44:13,490 ERROR trial_runner.py:886 -- Trial train_tune_43fd5_00007: Error processing event.
NoneType: None
Result for train_tune_43fd5_00007:
  date: 2022-08-16_15-44-13
  experiment_id: f79be7b9e98a43f1a41893071c4e1f6b
  hostname: 0e26c6a24ffa
  node_ip: 172.17.0.2
  pid: 41730
  timestamp: 1660664653
  trial_id: 43fd5_00007
  
2022-08-16 15:44:13,493 ERROR trial_runner.py:886 -- Trial train_tune_43fd5_00002: Error processing event.
NoneType: None
Result for train_tune_43fd5_00002:
  date: 2022-08-16_15-44-13
  experiment_id: 8e7422287e3e44f9b2e7b249a8ae18cd
  hostname: 0e26c6a24ffa
  node_ip: 172.17.0.2
  pid: 41720
  timestamp: 1660664653
  trial_id: 43fd5_00002
  
2022-08-16 15:44:13,512 ERROR trial_runner.py:886 -- Trial train_tune_43fd5_00006: Error processing event.
NoneType: None
Result for train_tune_43fd5_00006:
  date: 2022-08-16_15-44-13
  experiment_id: 2d56b152a6a34e1f9e26dad1aec25d00
  hostname: 0e26c6a24ffa
  node_ip: 172.17.0.2
  pid: 41728
  timestamp: 1660664653
  trial_id: 43fd5_00006
  
2022-08-16 15:44:13,527 ERROR trial_runner.py:886 -- Trial train_tune_43fd5_00008: Error processing event.
NoneType: None
Result for train_tune_43fd5_00008:
  date: 2022-08-16_15-44-13
  experiment_id: b2158026b3b947bfbb9c3da4e6f7b977
  hostname: 0e26c6a24ffa
  node_ip: 172.17.0.2
  pid: 41732
  timestamp: 1660664653
  trial_id: 43fd5_00008
  
2022-08-16 15:44:13,543 ERROR trial_runner.py:886 -- Trial train_tune_43fd5_00009: Error processing event.
NoneType: None
Result for train_tune_43fd5_00009:
  date: 2022-08-16_15-44-13
  experiment_id: 6b5a73f09241440085bd6c09f6f681e9
  hostname: 0e26c6a24ffa
  node_ip: 172.17.0.2
  pid: 41734
  timestamp: 1660664653
  trial_id: 43fd5_00009
  
(func pid=41726) 2022-08-16 15:44:13,484        ERROR function_runner.py:286 -- Runner Thread raised error.
(func pid=41726) Traceback (most recent call last):
(func pid=41726)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 277, in run
(func pid=41726)     self._entrypoint()
(func pid=41726)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 352, in entrypoint
(func pid=41726)     self._status_reporter.get_checkpoint(),
(func pid=41726)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/tracing/tracing_helper.py", line 462, in _resume_span
(func pid=41726)     return method(self, *_args, **_kwargs)
(func pid=41726)   File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/function_runner.py", line 645, in _trainable_func
(func pid=41726)     output = fn()
(func pid=41726)   File "example_hpo_working.py", line 76, in train_tune
(func pid=41726)     model = LightningMNISTClassifier(config)
(func pid=41726) NameError: name 'LightningMNISTClassifier' is not defined
2022-08-16 15:44:13,660 ERROR trial_runner.py:886 -- Trial train_tune_43fd5_00004: Error processing event.
NoneType: None
Result for train_tune_43fd5_00004:
  date: 2022-08-16_15-44-13
  experiment_id: 60f51e072c7942bdb5d9298e0e147555
  hostname: 0e26c6a24ffa
  node_ip: 172.17.0.2
  pid: 41724
  timestamp: 1660664653
  trial_id: 43fd5_00004
  
2022-08-16 15:44:13,687 ERROR trial_runner.py:886 -- Trial train_tune_43fd5_00005: Error processing event.
NoneType: None
Result for train_tune_43fd5_00005:
  date: 2022-08-16_15-44-13
  experiment_id: 79701d1c19ac4c55b5a73746c1872724
  hostname: 0e26c6a24ffa
  node_ip: 172.17.0.2
  pid: 41726
  timestamp: 1660664653
  trial_id: 43fd5_00005
  
== Status ==
Current time: 2022-08-16 15:44:13 (running for 00:00:05.46)
Memory usage on this node: 16.4/86.4 GiB
Using FIFO scheduling algorithm.
Resources requested: 0/64 CPUs, 0/0 GPUs, 0.0/62.79 GiB heap, 0.0/9.31 GiB objects
Result logdir: /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08
Number of trials: 10/10 (10 ERROR)
+------------------------+----------+------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
| Trial name             | status   | loc              |   batch_size |   layer_1_size |   layer_2_size |          lr |
|------------------------+----------+------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------|
| train_tune_43fd5_00000 | ERROR    | 172.17.0.2:41684 |           64 |             64 |            256 | 0.00233834  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00001 | ERROR    | 172.17.0.2:41718 |           64 |             64 |            256 | 0.00155955  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00002 | ERROR    | 172.17.0.2:41720 |          128 |            128 |             64 | 0.00399358  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00003 | ERROR    | 172.17.0.2:41722 |          128 |            128 |             64 | 0.000184477 |
| train_tune_43fd5_00004 | ERROR    | 172.17.0.2:41724 |          128 |             64 |            128 | 0.0221855   |
| train_tune_43fd5_00005 | ERROR    | 172.17.0.2:41726 |           64 |            128 |            128 | 0.00041038  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00006 | ERROR    | 172.17.0.2:41728 |           64 |             64 |            256 | 0.0105243   |
| train_tune_43fd5_00007 | ERROR    | 172.17.0.2:41730 |          128 |             32 |            256 | 0.000929454 |
| train_tune_43fd5_00008 | ERROR    | 172.17.0.2:41732 |           64 |             64 |            128 | 0.00176483  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00009 | ERROR    | 172.17.0.2:41734 |          128 |             32 |            256 | 0.000113077 |
+------------------------+----------+------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
Number of errored trials: 10
+------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Trial name             |   # failures | error file                                                                                                                                                        |
|------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| train_tune_43fd5_00000 |            1 | /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08/train_tune_43fd5_00000_0_batch_size=64,layer_1_size=64,layer_2_size=256,lr=0.0023_2022-08-16_15-44-08/error.txt  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00001 |            1 | /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08/train_tune_43fd5_00001_1_batch_size=64,layer_1_size=64,layer_2_size=256,lr=0.0016_2022-08-16_15-44-10/error.txt  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00002 |            1 | /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08/train_tune_43fd5_00002_2_batch_size=128,layer_1_size=128,layer_2_size=64,lr=0.0040_2022-08-16_15-44-10/error.txt |
| train_tune_43fd5_00003 |            1 | /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08/train_tune_43fd5_00003_3_batch_size=128,layer_1_size=128,layer_2_size=64,lr=0.0002_2022-08-16_15-44-10/error.txt |
| train_tune_43fd5_00004 |            1 | /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08/train_tune_43fd5_00004_4_batch_size=128,layer_1_size=64,layer_2_size=128,lr=0.0222_2022-08-16_15-44-10/error.txt |
| train_tune_43fd5_00005 |            1 | /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08/train_tune_43fd5_00005_5_batch_size=64,layer_1_size=128,layer_2_size=128,lr=0.0004_2022-08-16_15-44-10/error.txt |
| train_tune_43fd5_00006 |            1 | /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08/train_tune_43fd5_00006_6_batch_size=64,layer_1_size=64,layer_2_size=256,lr=0.0105_2022-08-16_15-44-10/error.txt  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00007 |            1 | /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08/train_tune_43fd5_00007_7_batch_size=128,layer_1_size=32,layer_2_size=256,lr=0.0009_2022-08-16_15-44-10/error.txt |
| train_tune_43fd5_00008 |            1 | /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08/train_tune_43fd5_00008_8_batch_size=64,layer_1_size=64,layer_2_size=128,lr=0.0018_2022-08-16_15-44-10/error.txt  |
| train_tune_43fd5_00009 |            1 | /root/ray_results/train_tune_2022-08-16_15-44-08/train_tune_43fd5_00009_9_batch_size=128,layer_1_size=32,layer_2_size=256,lr=0.0001_2022-08-16_15-44-10/error.txt |
+------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example_hpo_working.py", line 89, in <module>
    num_samples=10)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/tune.py", line 741, in run
    raise TuneError("Trials did not complete", incomplete_trials)
ray.tune.error.TuneError: ('Trials did not complete', [train_tune_43fd5_00000, train_tune_43fd5_00001, train_tune_43fd5_00002, train_tune_43fd5_00003, train_tune_43fd5_00004, train_tune_43fd5_00005, train_tune_43fd5_00006, train_tune_43fd5_00007, train_tune_43fd5_00008, train_tune_43fd5_00009])
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: it should perform HPO using ray-tune on a network generated with pytorch.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a longer stacktrace where the real error is printed?
Also could you go to the result folder and see the error file?

Usually result folder is under `~/ray_results`.

Comment: thanks a mil, i added the full trace, but i'm at the word limit for a question, so do you think this is more helpful or will i add what's in ~/ray_results because of character limitation i can't fit both?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a typo in your code:

```py
def __init__(self, config):
  super(LightningMNISTClassifier, self).__init__()
  self.layer_1_size = config["layer_1_size"]
  self.layer_2_size = config["layer_2_size"]
  self.lr = config["lr"]
  self.batch_size = config["batch_size"]
```

You need to define `LightningMNISTClassifier` properly. Maybe try using this example?

https://docs.ray.io/en/master/tune/examples/includes/mnist_ptl_mini.html

Note that you may need to install the latest version of Ray.